# Not able to refresh div automatically in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I wish to refresh the data of a particular div without reloading the entire page, although this is happening with the code that i am using, but the issue is that the css/layout of the entire page is also getting disturbed. Can anyone tell how to refresh the div without disturbing the layout
controller

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller 
    {
        public function dashboard()
            {
                $data['main'] = "admin/header";
                $data['instant_reqtotal'] = $this->admin_model->getreqtotal();
                $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
            }
    }
```

View

```
<div id="instanthirewidget">
    <?php echo $instant_reqtotal; ?>
</div>
```

Model

```
public function getreqtotal()
    {
        $this->db->where('status','pending');
        $query=$this->db->get('instanthire');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

script used for reloading

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadlink(){
    $('#instanthirewidget').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/dashboard',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink();
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() 
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: For this make an ajax call

Comment: By the way, is that correct dashboard.php. it shouldn't be only dashboard ?

Comment: @Naveed Ramzan sorry it was a typing error, rectified it

Comment: @Mayank Pandey tried that but the error is still the same, actually the view is getting loaded on top of the previous view

Comment: @user3732711 : its ok. secondly in CI a call to controller can be handled via Ajax call not only LOAD. So you need to use Ajax Post call. if you want to use load only, then you need to execute this function and save output in a file and then you can load that file. Of course its not a recommended method.

Comment: Before refreshing you should remove contents from the div and then do a ajax call to load the contents.

Comment: @Sushil Kumar Singh done but nothing happening

Comment: Use Ajax to fetch data/view from controller. One of the user @Mayank has answered it in the correct way. Do that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are returning a view inside a view. Change your approach like this:

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $data['main'] = "admin/header";
    $instant_reqtotal = $this->admin_model->getreqtotal();

    echo $instant_reqtotal;

    exit;
}

$.ajax({
    url : '...',
    method : '...',
    data : {...},
    success : function(response)    // response contains the $instant_reqtotal value in it
    {
        $('#instanthirewidget').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to load a view, and then load header view iniside that view seperately, so that if there are changes in header i dont have to go to every view to make the changes, if i change my dashboard controller, it will not fullfill my purpose

Comment: and besides i tried your way also but it is giving me undefined variable error

Comment: Ideally above solution given by @Mayank should work.